# Download of file during NSIS installer run freezes at "connecting"

Tags: nsis, miniconda

I want to create an installer for a custom python package over conda using NSIS. There are already some macros that help to create such an installer: https://github.com/faph/NSIS-Conda-Macros

They basically try to find conda und the computer and if it is not installed, download it for the user.

And here comes my problem. When the installer runs and tries to download the file, it stucks at the phase "connecting" and never downloads anything.

I have looked in the source code of NSIS-COnda-Macros, and they use:

```
!define CONDA_URL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe

NSISdl::download /TIMEOUT=1800000 ${CONDA_URL} conda_setup.exe
```

to download the conda_setup.exe. Also if I try to run this isolated, the download doesn't work. Is `NSISdl::download` basically broken, or is it used in a wrong way here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSISdl does not support the HTTPS protocol. Use [INetC](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in) instead, it uses the same network API as Internet Explorer.

Comment: Well, I already found that plugin, but I didn't find out how it can be installed/included. I just found the download file, but I didn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Put it (the .dll) in NSIS\Plugins (NSIS 2) or the correct plug-in sub folder (NSIS 3).