# NSIS: Access https site in ExecDos

Tags: anaconda, nsis

I'm trying to create an installer for a python based scientific application. We use Anaconda as a python distribution and I found https://github.com/faph/NSIS-Conda-Macros to help me setup an installer for conda packages.

However, downloading the miniconda installer failed. I was able to solve that with the help of:
[Download of file during NSIS installer run freezes at "connecting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467921/download-of-file-during-nsis-installer-run-freezes-at-connecting)

But I found no way to make the updating of packages work. They use:

```
  ExecDos::exec /DETAILED '"$CONDA" update -y -q conda' "" ""
```

conda then tries to connect over https to get the most recent packages from their server. The connection always times out. When i run the same code directly in cmd it runs fine.

So my question:
Is it even possible to access https in ExecDos::exec? Does anyone have an idea to work-around the issue?

Comment: ExecDos has nothing to do with downloading, it basically does "cmd.exe /c..." Is this even a programming question? Seems like a Anaconda bug to me...

Comment: In Anaconda everything is fine. The problem is that https is no accessible in the sub-process started by  ExecDos::exec

Comment: What is the value of $conda? What happens if you add `Exec '"cmd.exe" /k' ` to the script and manually run the update there?

Comment: Thanks for your help. `Exec '"cmd.exe" /k'` really helped to debug. so far i found out that conda.exe from `AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe` always gives a connection error but if i use `AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat` it seems to work.